# Center items in RadListView in Nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript, radlistview

I can not center the elements of a RadViewList in the middle of the screen in a nativescript-angular app. 
See in Playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ZFOHYN&v=4

I tried several methods without result: FlexBoxLayout, horizontalAlignment and verticalAligmnent, inline css, css display flex..

See in Playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ZFOHYN&v=4

---

```
<StackLayout class="page">
    <GridLayout tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
        <RadListView col="1" [items]="name" 
            selectionBehavior="LongPress"
            multipleSelection="true" reorderMode="Drag" 
            backgroundColor="gray"
            height="100%" itemReorder="true" padding="10">
            <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
                <GridLayout>
                    <Label [text]="item" textAlignment="center" 
                        witdh="95%"
                        height="95%" margin="5px" padding="15px"
                        backgroundColor="red" fontSize="30"></Label>
                </GridLayout>
            </ng-template>

            <ListViewGridLayout tkListViewLayout 
                 scrollDirection="Vertical"
                ios:itemHeight="250" spanCount="5"> 
            </ListViewGridLayout>
        </RadListView>
    </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

---

the element stay at the top left corner !!

Comment: ... also, there is a spelling error in `Label`- it says `witdh="95%"` instead of `width`.

Comment: @Tim  thank you but that does not solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try adding vertical alignment like this to your inner grid:

```
<GridLayout class="vcenter">
...
```

having this in your stylesheet:

```
.vcenter {
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

Comment: @tsaadi vertical-align: center indeed works, but you are not suppose to set the height of RadListView explicitly. You are setting it to 100% in your Playground sample. Also you may have to remove the outer StackLayout, which is unnecessary, or if you like to stack items, you can remove GridLayout and assign vertical center on StackLayout  If you still face issues, please submit your updated sample.

Comment: @Manoj what I want to do is precisely center the Label inside RadViewList, which must have an explicit height. In other words (use the playground or see the screenshot) center the Label (in red) inside the RadViewList (in gray).
playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=acMEE0&v=2
Screenshot: https://ibb.co/tXq9QqV

Answer (score -1):

Please remove this lines

```
 <ListViewGridLayout tkListViewLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" ios:itemHeight="250" spanCount="5"> 
 </ListViewGridLayout>
```

and should work as expected

Comment: This line is important for the application, it defines Specific Item Layout. https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/professional-ui-components/ListView/item-layouts

Comment: well, you explicit ask to keep it on the left side for ios, using:  ios:itemHeight="250" spanCount="5". Remove spanCount="5", and it would be in center